# GKSession Problems - Objective-C GameKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gamekit

Ok, I've been trying to create my own GKSession object and the delegate method is giving me an error in the console that I haven't figured out how to fix just yet. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions or had encountered this problem? *Just a note - the variable peerStatus is defined elsewhere in my code. The peer can either be given a status of "kServer" or "kClient". I would rather define each to be in GKSessionModeServer or GKSessionModeClient because I've read that if the peer is in GKSessionModePeer, performance time is actually slower because it has to do the work of both Client and Server.

```
- (GKSession *)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type {
    if (peerStatus == kServer) {
        GKSession *session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"Josh_Land" displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeServer];
        return [session autorelease];
    }
    else {
        GKSession *session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"Josh_Land" displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeClient];
        return [session autorelease]; 
    }
}
```

The whole error code is:

Listening on port 56386
2009-06-30 10:31:41.892 GKTank[17756:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GKInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'A vaild GKSession object with a GKSessionModePeer mode must be supplied, or to create a default GKSession object return 'nil' in the implementation of -peerPickerController:sessionForConnectionType:. Supplied object was: sent 0 data packets : rush (0 packets 0 bytes): rely (0 packets 0 bytes) : rtry (0 packets 0 bytes) : sack (0 packets 0 bytes) : current weighted average rtt (0 ms) with session mode: 0'
2009-06-30 10:31:41.893 GKTank[17756:20b] Stack: (
    807902715,
    2452446779,
    807986683,
    807986522,
    927035842,
    927037074,
    927038407,
    815223834,
    927038949,
    9245,
    8562,
    814709201,
    815110321,
    815119058,
    815114270,
    814813151,
    814722763,
    814748641,
    839148405,
    807687520,
    807683624,
    839142449,
    839142646,
    814752238
)

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the error you are getting.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post with the error code now. It actually works if I run configure the GKSession to GKSessionModePeer for both, but I'm trying to stay away form that. I would rather designate the session to be either in Server or Client mode. I was wondering if this is even possible right now (where it just came out, could there be some bug in the code??) or is it my code?

Comment: I don't know the answer either but have you tested to see if it's actually slower in any way that matters?  If you've only read it's slower, but not actually seen a performance hit from it then this could well be premature optimization.

That said, it would be interesting to see what is going wrong with your test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't actually implemented anything using GameKit yet, but just looking over the documentation, it looks like you can only use GKPeerPickerController if you are using GKSessionModePeer. If you want to use GKSessionModeServer/Client, you need to work directly with the sessions and their delegate. See the section in the Game Kit Programming Guide on [Implementing a Server](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-DontLinkElementID_4) and [Connecting to a Service](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-DontLinkElementID_5).

Your main functionality would revolve around the GKSessionDelegate method 

`-session:peer:didChangeState:` in both client and server modes and 
`-acceptConnectionFromPeer:error:` and  `-denyConnectionFromPeer:` in server mode.